# Why is my partial influence child-of-constraint rotation bouncing back?

Tags: constraints

I'm trying to make a mileage meter using the *Child-of* constraint with a partial influence of 0.1.

In theory, rotating the first marker should gradually rotate the rest consecutively down the line. However, the third marker consistently bounces back to its original position.

[GIF of problem](https://imgur.com/a/L6lLDsH).

Changing the constraint influence value is not an option for this project, but I have tried, and the same problem arises but on a further marker.

[image: These are my settings - default]

Comment: Let's say you rotate 180 degrees.  What is your rotation?  18 degrees.  Now rotate 1 more degree, and your rotation, as seen by any constraints, is now -179 degrees, 10% of which is -17.9 degrees.  If you want to do this, use a driver instead.  This should be well answered elsewhere, although I'm not, personally, looking for a link; usually, it comes up for people using copy rotation, which is a better fit for you here (that's all you're using your constraint for); but all constraints are going to work like this.  They see orientations, not raw transform values.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: @Nathan  I looked at some driver tutorials and this will work perfectly! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.